# How proper get content from url in GO?

Tags: go

For example I need content from page https://aliexpress.ru/item/4001275226820.html

In Postman and in browser I get html content of page

But when I try use GO i can`t get content

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://aliexpress.ru/item/4001275226820.html")
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if err != nil {panic(err)}

    html, err1 := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err1 != nil {panic(err1)}

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", html)
}
```

But get panic "stopped after 10 redirects"
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Understand why aliexpress.ru redirects your request. One possible reason could be missing or wrong headers. Then add the relevant headers.

Comment: thank you for response, I just thought postman also not send special headers. Thank you, I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code gets me a 200 response. You might be able to simplify it, but should be enough to get you started:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "net/http"
)

func cookies() ([]*http.Cookie, error) {
   req, err := http.NewRequest(
      "HEAD", "https://login.aliexpress.ru/sync_cookie_write.htm", nil,
   )
   if err != nil {
      return nil, err
   }
   val := req.URL.Query()
   val.Set("acs_random_token", "1")
   req.URL.RawQuery = val.Encode()
   res, err := new(http.Transport).RoundTrip(req)
   if err != nil {
      return nil, err
   }
   return res.Cookies(), nil
}

func main() {
   req, err := http.NewRequest(
      "HEAD", "https://aliexpress.ru/item/4001275226820.html", nil,
   )
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   cooks, err := cookies()
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   for _, cook := range cooks {
      if cook.Name == "xman_f" {
         req.AddCookie(cook)
      }
   }
   res, err := new(http.Transport).RoundTrip(req)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", res)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I add cookiejar to client and it help me:


 jar, _ := cookiejar.New(&cookiejar.Options{});

 client := &http.Client{
  Jar: jar,
 }